# Generate uniform \fbox height

Tags: tables, templates

To make a flexible document structure with bordered tabulars, I want to have uniform heights of specific frames, without specifying the frame height explicitly, because the height is variable. My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.4in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% INPUT
\newcommand\Subject{The subject rule is sometimes one rule and sometimes two rules}
\newcommand\Author{API}
\newcommand\Audience{Stack Exchange}
\newcommand\HeadTitle{This frame is too low!}

\begin{document}
\centering\fbox{ 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.5\linewidth}{r|p{0.75\linewidth}}
                \textbf{Subject:} & \Subject \\
                \textbf{Author:} & \Author \\
                \textbf{Audience:} & \Audience \\
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
        \textbf{\HeadTitle}
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{minipage} }
\end{document}
```

Giving the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using an additonal package is an option for you, then `tcolorbox` could be used for the job.

Here, the two embedded boxes are set by the `tcbitemize` environment which allows to set the boxes to an equal height. It takes two compilations to see the effect.

For the example, I used a `2mm` distance between the two boxes. This distance is put as `raster column skip=2mm` and is also subtracted from the width of the second box (`width=0.4\linewidth-2mm`).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage[raster]{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% INPUT
\newcommand\Subject{The subject rule is sometimes one rule and sometimes two rules}
\newcommand\Author{API}
\newcommand\Audience{Stack Exchange}
\newcommand\HeadTitle{This frame is too low!}

\begin{document}
\centering\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
\begin{tcbitemize}[size=fbox,sharp corners,
  colframe=black,colback=white,
  raster equal height,raster force size=false,
  raster equal skip=0pt,raster column skip=2mm]
\tcbitem[width=0.6\linewidth]
        \begin{tabular*}{0.5\linewidth}{r|p{0.75\linewidth}}
                \textbf{Subject:} & \Subject \\
                \textbf{Author:} & \Author \\
                \textbf{Audience:} & \Audience \\
        \end{tabular*}
\tcbitem[width=0.4\linewidth-2mm]
        \textbf{\HeadTitle}
\end{tcbitemize}%
\end{minipage} }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works and I think this is an elegant solution

Comment: @API I'm glad that this was helpful :-)